# Making bold tick labels in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

How do I make the tick labels bold? Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization[scientific axes, 
                     x axis = {attribute=x,label,length=8.4cm},
                     y axis = {attribute = y, label},
                     visualize as scatter,
                     all axes = grid]
  data{x,y
    0, 3.655
    2.40, 13.64
    4 , 23.58
    5, 44};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be `font=\bfseries` in the options of `tikzpicture`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like this is a not-so-much polished area of the CVS version but here is one possiblity. I also noticed that some `node style` options are not passed properly so keep in mind that it is still in a work-in-progress status.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \datavisualization[scientific axes,
                     all axes={grid,
                     ticks={tick typesetter/.code={%
                                   \pgfmathparse{####1}%
                                   $\mathbf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}$%
                                   }
                            }
                     },
                     x axis = {attribute=x,label,length=4cm},
                     y axis = {attribute = y, label},
                     visualize as scatter
                     ]
  data{x,y
    0, 3.655
    2.40, 13.64
    4 , 23.58
    5, 44};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]