# What are the new features in TikZ/pgf 3.0?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Since the December 20, 2013, we have new major release of the wonderful TikZ/pgf package: version 3.0.0! <sup>1</sup>

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a nice human readable list of changes, that goes to some depth and maybe even provides some examples. [This page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.0/) probably comes closest to it: <sup>2</sup>

Therefore, I would like to ask you to point out some of the new features and give examples of their usage! A bounty might be awarded `;-)`.

---

<sup>1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/

2. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%203.0.0/</sup>

Comment: Is this an official release? It hasn't made it to CTAN, yet, and thus is not part of either major TeX distribution.

Comment: it is not a major release but a release candidate.

Comment: @cgnieder: It is and CTAN is working on releasing it. Once it's on CTAN it will in the distros.

Comment: @MartinSchröder good news :)

Comment: @MartinSchröder It is a month and a half and still not on CTAN.  Any time prognosis when this is going to be released?

Comment: Any one knows if there is a build-in support for dimensioning in new Tikz? As in this question asking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14901/dimensioning-of-a-technical-drawing-in-tikz

Comment: Finally [pgf 3.0.0 makes it to ctan and to all its the mirrors](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/msg06147.html) :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because all information is contained in the [changelog](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/ChangeLog) which is an off-site resource.

Comment: But the changelog does not give an overview like the community wiki answer below.

Comment: @HenriMenke Where is the change log located?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Some of the new features have *already* been shown on the site.

I report some examples (in alphabetical order):

#### `angles`

- [Label angle with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/label-angle-with-tikz/136971#136971)
- [Improvement of PSTricks code for drawing of balls in a triangular box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112906/improvement-of-pstricks-code-for-drawing-of-balls-in-a-triangular-box/146636#146636)
- [How do I draw a little red square to label my right triangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154351/how-do-i-draw-a-little-red-square-to-label-my-right-triangle/154357#154357)

#### `arrows.meta`

- [Partial triangular arrows with TikZ/PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138917/partial-triangular-arrows-with-tikz-pgf/138933#138933)
- [Custom Tikz arrowhead with bar before triangle 45](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150207/custom-tikz-arrowhead-with-bar-before-triangle-45/150213#150213)
- [Tikz drawing different type of arrows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141805/tikz-drawing-different-type-of-arrows/141818#141818)
- [TikZ: configuring arrow tip appearance not working according to documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136190/tikz-configuring-arrow-tip-appearance-not-working-according-to-documentation/136193#136193)
- [How to draw shape as 'curved arrows' with text (with tikz)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153922/1952)

#### `babel`

- [Problem with babel and tikz using \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw/166819#166819)
- [tikz declare function and babel french option](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/tikz-declare-function-and-babel-french-option/187574#187574)
- [Tikz shortandoff-on newcommand problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163929/tikz-shortandoff-on-newcommand-problem/163979#163979)

#### `datavisualization`

- [Making bold tick labels in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106600/making-bold-tick-labels-in-tikz#106634)
- [TikZ datavisualization example fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67146/tikz-datavisualization-example-fail)
- [pgfplots: mark max/min value of a function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46176/pgfplots-mark-max-min-value-of-a-function/46206#46206)

#### `graphdrawing`

- [How can I make the diamond-e framework in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141358/how-can-i-make-the-diamond-e-framework-in-tikz/141595#141595)
- [Overlap in graphing TikZ picture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144360/overlap-in-graphing-tikz-picture/144370#144370)
- [TikZ graph with interesting vertices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144261/tikz-graph-with-interesting-vertices/144269#144269)
- [Chapter Dependency Diagram in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118801/chapter-dependency-diagram-in-latex/118835#118835)
- [drawing tree using tikz, child overlap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60571/drawing-tree-using-tikz-child-overlap/60625#60625)

#### `pics`

- [How can I draw a TikZ element multiple times against a shaded background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126161/how-can-i-draw-a-tikz-element-multiple-times-against-a-shaded-background/151772#151772)
- [How can I rotate and mirror a tikz picture in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151141/how-can-i-rotate-and-mirror-a-tikz-picture-in-latex/151574#151574)

#### `quotes`

- [Label angle with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20826/label-angle-with-tikz/136971#136971)
- [Use \usetikzlibrary{quotes} with \MakeOuterQuote{"} from csquots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108190/use-usetikzlibraryquotes-with-makeouterquote-from-csquots)
- [How do I draw a little red square to label my right triangle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154351/how-do-i-draw-a-little-red-square-to-label-my-right-triangle/154357#154357)

Comment: Oh, I'm looking forward to `pics`!

Comment: The graph drawing library is amazing. Making things so much easier! When will 3.0 reach TeXLive?

Comment: What? No faded drop shadow? `:(`

Comment: `texdoc tikz` brings up the old documentation (v2.1 rather than 3.0), why?

Comment: @CodeMocker: make sure to copy the `doc` directory in your personal tree. I did that way and `texdoc` is opening correctly the new documentation.

Comment: @CodeMocker The new version has until now not been uploaded to CTAN, and therefore no update for the major TeX distributions is available.

Comment: @Speravir: CodeMoker was referring to the documentation. Actually, to read a package documentation via `texdoc`, it not necessary that the package is on CTAN. Just put in you personal tree, according to the TDS structure, a `doc` folder and copy there the pdf, say `mypkg.pdf`. You will be able to open it through `texdoc mypkg`. However, according to [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/discussion/477362/thread/340b50b1/?limit=50#99f5), the new version _has been uploaded to CTAN_.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Hmm, I read it this way, that he/she thought to already have version 3.0. Regarding Till’s information: OK, it is until now not included into the repository.

Comment: The module `\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}` - which is necessary for the answer of this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/188386/42225 of mine - also needs v.3.0.0. However, it seems that the nonlinear transformations don't always work as intendend...

Answer (score 30):

With TikZ 3.0, you can use blend modes.

> A blend mode specifies how colors mix when you paint on a canvas. Normally, if you paint a red box on a green circle, the red color will completely replace the green circle. However, in some situations you might
> also wish the red color to somehow "mix" or "blend" with the green circle. We
> already saw that, using
> transparency, we can draw something without completely obscuring the
> background. Blending is a similar
> operation, only here we mix colors in more complicated ways.
>
> **Note:** Blending is a rather **"advanced" feature of PDF**. Most renderers, let
> alone printers, will have
> trouble rendering blending correctly.

Below is an example of `screen` blend mode (there are 16 modes: `normal`, `multiply`, `screen`,  `overlay`, `darken`, `lighten`, `color dodge`, `color burn`, `hard light`, `soft light`, `difference`, `exclusion`, `hue`, `saturation`, `color`, `luminosity`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz [blend group=screen] {
  \fill[red!90!black]   ( 90:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[green!80!black] (210:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[blue!90!black] (330:.6) circle (1);
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

With TikZ 3.0 arrives `math` library.

> This library defines a simple mathematical language to define simple functions and perform sequences of basic mathematical operations.

Here is a code from the manual (p.629), slightly modified to include function use.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=50]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  function step(\n){ return 45/\n; };
  function first(\n){ return step(\n)/2; };
  function next(\n){ return first(\n)+2*step(\n); };
  function testcircle(\a){
    real \s; \s = step(\a);
    for \k in {first(\a),next(\a),...,360}{
      % set the color
      if \k>270 then { let \c = orange; } else {
        if \k>180 then { let \c = blue; } else {
          if \k>90 then { let \c = red; } else {
            let \c = green;
          };
        };
      };
      { % "print" the path command
        \path[fill=\c!50, draw=\c] (\k:0.5cm) -- (\k:1cm) --
          (\k+\s:1cm) -- (\k+\s:0.5cm) -- cycle;
      };
    }; % end for loop
  }; % end test circle
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{testcircle(4);}
    \begin{scope}[scale=-2.1]
      \tikzmath{testcircle(13);}
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that code looks almost like one sees in normal looking languages. A normal looking function definition and even a normal looking "if then else". May be I should switch to Latex programming from now on. This is very good news. Can one call these functions from Latex outside `\begin{tikzpicture}`? Or these functions can only be used inside `tikzpicture`?

Comment: @Nasser yes we can. If you look at the manual you can see examples outside `tikzpicture`. But don't be so happy : not everything is possible. It is really "math" library. You can't manipulate "strings" easily (you can still hook to standard (La)TeX for doing this). For example I was not able to create function that returns a color (like `green!50`) and use it after in the path. But may be somebody will tell us how to do it ;)

Comment: @Kpym You may use `return "..."` to return a string. Then you may define a new `.math expr` handler to use _math expressions_ for any pgf/tikz key.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I tried to return string, it works well if I use it in a node text, but I was not able to use it in a style. I'll check with `.math exp` (I was not aware of the existence of this handler). Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: @Kpym You must write your own `.math expr` handler like `\pgfkeysdef{/handlers/.math expr}{\pgfmathparse{#1}\pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.expand once=\pgfmathresult}}`

Comment: @PaulGaborit I failed to create a function that takes one parameter, let say `\c` (a color like "blue") and then returns `\c!\d` whare `\d` is some integer (for example 50). Can you do this in `math` library ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for the tip `.math expr`.