# Problem with babel and tikz using \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

I'm trying the next code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Simple arrow: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but it doesn't work. It throws the errors:

- `! Argument of \language@active@arg> has an extra }.`
- `! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg> was complete.<to be read again>\par \draw[->]`

What can I do if it works right without the babel package?

Comment: It seems that `\usepackage[english]{babel}` works, but `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` does not.  Also, not sure why you have `[pdftex,spanish]` options for `\documentclass` - FYI, I am not that familiar with `babel`.

Comment: Add `\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}` after `\begin{document}`. < and > are active characters in Spanish.

Comment: @PeterGrill using the `pdftex` option is not necessary with modern LaTeX systems (the driver is automatically detected). Using the idiomatic localization (`spanish`, in this case) as class option has the advantage that all language-sensitive packages (for example, `babel`, `cleveref`) that can eventually be loaded will pick it and produce the idiomatic localizations.

Comment: @Mario I've updated my answer with new information that might be of interest for you.

Comment: Neatly done with babel library, thanks @GonzaloMedina.

Comment: @Mario You're welcome. Don't forget that you can accept the answer that you consider best solved your problem by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: @Malipivo : Thanks so much. Your solution was all I needed. About 5 hours, no stopping looking for this. You made my day :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The problem is that the `spanish` module for `babel` makes `>` and `<` active characters for its special management of Spanish quotations.

### Update:

With PGF/TikZ version 3.0.0 there's a `babel` library that solves the problems produced by changes to category codes made by some `babel` modules, so it's enough to load the library:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

Simple arrows: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);

\end{document}
```

(Thanks to **Claudio Fiandrino** for pointing this out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw/166775?noredirect=1#comment383307_166775)).

### PGF/TikZ version 2.10

To deactivate the undesired redefinition for `tikzpicture`s, but maintaining it for other parts of the document, you can use

```
  execute at begin picture={\deactivatequoting},
  execute at end picture={\activatequoting}
```

for every `tikzpicture`. Notice that this approach has two advantages:

1. No extra packages are required.
2. It also produces the desired result when using the command version `\tikz` (see example code below).

The code:

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
every picture/.append style={
  execute at begin picture={\deactivatequoting},
  execute at end picture={\activatequoting}
  }
}
\begin{document}

Simple arrows: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz\draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, don't use `pdftex` option; modern LaTeX systems detect the driver automatically.

Comment: With TikZ 3.0.0 there is a `babel` library on purpose: see [Tikz shortandoff-on newcommand problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163929/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Ah, that's very useful information, thank you! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Personally, I think it is one the major features introduced in version 3 in terms of utility (for my own purposes of course).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I agree. Not having to introduce special fixes for (some of) the `babel` modules is a great advantage.

Comment: With TikZ 3.0.1 and subfig, using a tikzpicture in a \subfloat{...} gives the old mess, even with the babel library.

Comment: I had errors with `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}` and `tikz-cd`, including the library fixed them. Thanks!

Comment: Also had errors with `german` in `babel` due to quotes in an `angles` picture with `quotes` for convenient labeling. Stumbled on the `shorthandoff` and `shorthandon` over [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340663/74942). Replacing the `\(de)activatequoting` with `\shorthandoff{"}`and `\shorthandon{"}` did the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

As noted by Malipivo, the `spanish` option of `babel` makes `>` active. You can make it inactive just inside (all) the `tikzpicture` environment locally, Add these in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}}{}{}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}}{}{}

\begin{document}

Simple arrow:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With TikZ 3.0.0 there is a `babel` library on purpose: see [Tikz shortandoff-on newcommand problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163929/13304).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino --- the problem with the `\usetikzpackage{babel}` is that it will not work if the `tikzpicture` is inside an `\ifthenelse{}{}{}` block --- is there a solution for this?

Comment: @Rmano: Actually, I don't know. It would be great if you can post a separate question for this: it will get more attention.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino done, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314884/babel-active-chars-ifthenelse-and-tikz

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need to use `spanish quotes`, just add `es-noquoting` to babel options and `TiKZ` arrows will appear again.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Simple arrow: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need `spanish quotes` use new `babel` TiKZ 3.0 library (as Claudio suggested). Here you have an example:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\begin{document}

Simple arrow: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) node[right] {<<Hola>>};
\end{tikzpicture}

<<Hola>>
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why, but none of the previous answers has worked for me. They showed me the right path though; adding just

```
\deactivatequoting
```

on the preambled fixed the problem.

Calling `babel` with `english` as well as `spanish` does the trick, too

```
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}
```

Comment: It is quite normal that calling `babel` with the `english` option placed *after* the `spanish` one does the trick: it means that the `english` settings of Babel apply by default, and in that case there is no bug. But most of the time, having their documents typeset with English conventions is not what people want when they write in Spanish :-)