# Compiler Error. Tikz and Arrow error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Im having a little problem with the Tikz package. I don't know why it doesn't want to compile if i want to do arrows instead of lines.  Im using the following code to create a diagram:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,matrix,shapes.symbols}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \matrix [column sep=15mm, row sep=4mm, every node/.style={
         text width=3cm,
        minimum height=1.75cm,
        text centered,
        draw=black,
        rounded corners,
        line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
    }] {
      \node (a1) {Controlador de solicitudes}; &
      \node (a2) {Receptor Satelital}; &
      \node (a3) {Alimentatión Inteligente}; \\
      &
      \node (b2) {Decodificador NMAE}; &
      \node (b3) {Interfaz Web}; \\
      &
      \node (c2) {Almacenamiento de Informacion}; &
      \node[xshift=15mm] (c3) {Autorizar y Autentificar}; \\
      &
      \node (d2) {Transmisor con GMS/GPRS}; &
      \node (d3) {Servidor Web}; \\
    };

    \begin{scope}[->, very thick]
      \draw (a1) -- (a2);
      \draw ([xshift=3mm]a1.south) |- ([yshift=3mm]d2.west);
      \draw (a2) -- (b2);
      \draw (b2) -- (c2);
      \draw (c2) -- (d2);
      \draw ([yshift=-3mm]d2.west) -| ([xshift=-3mm]a1.south);
      \draw[-, dashed] (d2) -- (d3);
      \draw ([xshift=5mm]b3.south) -- ([xshift=-10mm]c3.north);
      \draw ([xshift=-10mm]c3.south) -- ([xshift=5mm]d3.north);
      \draw ([xshift=-5mm]d3.north) -- ([xshift=-5mm]b3.south);
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

I realized that the problem is the -> after the \begin{scope}. If i delete that it compiles perfect.

What can it be? Im i loading the wrong package?

Thanks !

Comment: Your code works just fine here, exactly what error do you get?

Comment: It works fine for me, too.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.
Here is the error: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a53brttbc

Comment: Do you use `babel` in your document? Can you create a complete example demonstrating the problem? (A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: I think your character encoding is not UTF-8 compatible.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Im actually using babel (spanish package). I realized that if i delete that it works perfectly. Is there a way that i can use both ? Thanks !

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`