# Conflict between babel and TikZ quotes library

Tags: babel, tikzlibrary

The MWE below gives error `language@active@arg" has extra }`.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,slovene]{babel}%
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) edge ["right", ->] (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Cause for it is option `slovenian` in `babel` which seem to redefine `"` somehow (if I remove this option, MWE work fine). Please, help me fix this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Problem with babel and tikz using \draw](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw)

Comment: @PaulGaborit I don't think that is a duplicate of the *question* even though the answer may be the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the `babel` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,slovene]{babel}%
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) edge ["right", ->] (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate, surely?

Comment: This was fast! Thank you. Before asking I search through SE, but didn't find similar question ...

Comment: @cfr maybe [Problem with babel and tikz using \draw](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw)

Comment: In my case I have problem only when use `quotes` library. Using all other TikZ libraries didn't make any troubles. Anyway, the answer is to my question and how to draw line is the same. SO it can be considered as duplicate.

Comment: @Zarko Yes. Unfortunately the search feature sucks. I asked a question yesterday despite being pretty sure I'd *read* a duplicate simply because I could not find it.

Comment: @Zarko The `quotes` library is a problem, as I understand it, because it conflicts with the shorthands which `babel` defines for some languages. For Spanish, TikZ causes issues even without it because the use of `<` conflicts.