# ! Argument of \language@active@arg has an extra }. (I use \includegraphics and russian)

Tags: russian

Here's my preamble:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{~}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

and problematic part of code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{"Figure 1_2_8(GIMP)".jpg}
```

When I try to compile the code I get this error:

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.69 ...idth=\textwidth]{"Figure 1_2_8(GIMP)".jpg}

? Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \language@active@arg" was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.69 ...idth=\textwidth]{"Figure 1_2_8(GIMP)".jpg}

?
```

I suppose it could be caused by incorrect using quotes. I tried use {} before {, but it didn't help. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: russian makes the quote " active. You could try `\shorthandoff{"}` before the graphic, but better is to avoid spaces in file names -- then you don't need quotes.

Comment: also unrelated to the error but you probably should replace `\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{center}` by `\centering`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That's what I keep telling everybody, but they still send me files with spaces and even Umlaut in the filename. :-(

Comment: @Andyc umlauts are imho fine, they are normal chars in unicode, but spaces should be avoided.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`"` is an active short hand character of `russianb.ldf` (package `babel`). It does not work in file names, because it is not expandable.

Three options:

- `\shorthandoff{"}`, see [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340661/argument-of-languageactivearg-has-an-extra-i-use-includegraphics-and-r#comment835775_340661) of Ulrike Fischer:

  ```
  \shorthandoff{"}%
  \includegraphics{"example image a"}%
  \shorthandon{"}%
  ```
- Macro `\dq` is the expandable version of the double quotes for languages with the double quote as shorthand (e.g., `russianb.ldf`, `ngermanb.ldf`).

  ```
   \includegraphics{\dq example image a\dq}%
  ```
- Package `grffile` adds some support for spaces in image file names:

  ```
  \usepackage{grffile}

  \includegraphics{example image a}
  ```

Comment: FYI with `ngerman` `\dq` didn't work for me: I got a different error, but still an error. `\shorthandoff{"}` worked fine.

Comment: @Andyc I didn't get any error with '\dq' and `ngerman` (either as package or language for `babel`) in any package order.