# Unexpected conflict between babels and tikzcd inside macros

Tags: macros, babel, tikz-cd

The following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[english, russian]{babel} % if I comment this line, the snippet works

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newcommand{\bullets}[1]{\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
    \bullets{
        \item
        \[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
              A \& B \\
              \arrow["\phi", from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \end{tikzcd}\]
    }
\end{document}
```

produces strange error `` Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `"\phi {\@@par  }'. ``, `Argument of \@secondoffive has an extra }.`, `Paragraph ended before \@secondoffive was complete.` and so on.

However, it has to do something with macros `bullets`, and/or with `\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}` — if I comment that line, it works fine. The following snippet also compiles correctly — in case the `tikzcd` isn't placed inside macros, or the arrow isn't named:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\newcommand{\bullets}[1]{\begin{itemize}#1\end{itemize}}

\begin{document}
    \bullets{
        \item
        \[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
              A \& B \\
              \arrow[from=1-1, to=1-2]
        \end{tikzcd}\]
    }
    \[\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
          A \& B \\
          \arrow["\phi", from=1-1, to=1-2]
    \end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

I understand that I can replace everywhere `bullets` with `begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` and not to use tikzcd in any type of macros, but I am kinda got used to them, so is there a way to make the first code version to compile?

I use pdfLaTex and Tex Live on Ubuntu.

Comment: I suppose that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/340661/134805) is relevant.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, thank you! I believe it answers my question, so I marked it as a duplicate.