# ! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra } in a tikz-cd diagram

Tags: languages, tikz-cd, russian

I am trying to insert a tikz-cd diagram which I have previously drawn in Obsidian into my TeX document. The code including the diagram is:

```tex
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[scale=3]
        \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} 
            \arrow[r, "\nabla \otimes \text{id}"] 
            \arrow[d, "\text{id} \otimes \nabla"] &
        \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} \arrow[d, "\nabla"] \\      
        \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} \arrow[r, "\nabla"] &
        \mathcal{A} 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
```

I get the following error:

```
Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.100 \end{tikzcd}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
```

My preamble:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 


\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.8,0.6}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1.0,0.4,0}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=L,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=C,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=12pt,
  numberstyle=\small\color{mygray},
}
\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Определение}
```

Googling this error, I've come across an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340661/argument-of-languageactivearg-has-an-extra-i-use-includegraphics-and-r) recommending finding some substitute for the `"` symbol. However, I have no idea how am I supposed to substitute `"` in a tikz-cd diagram.

P.S. This is my first time using tikz-cd in a TeX document, and not inside the Obsidian environment, so errors in my use of tikz-cd are also possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to load the Ti*k*Z library `babel`.

By the way, `times` is obsolete and actually does nothing at all when Cyrillic is involved. The package `tempora` has support of a Times-like Cyrillic font; I also load `newtxmath` for Times-like math symbols.

Also `\text{id}` is wrong and should be `\mathrm{id}`.

Change the order of package loading: `hyperref` should be last. No need for either `cmap` or `inputenc`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%\usepackage{cmap}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tempora}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.8,0.6}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1.0,0.4,0}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
  belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=L,
  xleftmargin=\parindent,
  language=C,
  showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{green!40!black},
  commentstyle=\itshape\color{purple!40!black},
  identifierstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{orange},
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=12pt,
  numberstyle=\small\color{mygray},
}
\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}

\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Определение}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[scale=3]
        \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} 
            \arrow[r, "\nabla \otimes \mathrm{id}"] 
            \arrow[d, "\mathrm{id} \otimes \nabla"] &
        \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} \arrow[d, "\nabla"] \\      
        \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} \arrow[r, "\nabla"] &
        \mathcal{A} 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]