# Tikz vs. babel: Problem with quotation marks and pgfmathsetlengthmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

I saw some tricks here [Problem with babel and tikz using \draw](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw)

but it seems I can't use them. 
If I say in my MWE 
`\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` 
`\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}`

and later 
`\def\Symbol{X}` 
`\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolwidth{0.5*width("\Symbol")}`, 
 he gives me

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `X' (in '0.5*width("X")').
```

What have I to do?

[image]

```
% I need
% arara: lualatex 
% if this is an important info.

\documentclass{article}

% needed:  ======
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}

% needed:  ======
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\def\Symbol{X}
\begin{document}
\section{Quotation Marks}
\enquote{test}
\glqq test 2\grqq

\section{TikZ}
% needed:  ======
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolwidth{0.5*width("\Symbol")}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolheight{0.5*height("\Symbol")}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\symbolwidth, y=\symbolheight]
\node[draw]{\Symbol};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Usage of `\Symbol` is irrelevant and also `csquotes`. Apparently the syntax is broken even if the `babel` library is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `babel` library enters the scene only inside a `tikzpicture` (thanks to Ulrike Fischer for pointing it out).

The problem is independent of `\Symbol` (also the simple `X` triggers the error) and of `csquotes`.

Workaround: use `\string"`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% needed:  ======
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}

% needed:  ======
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\def\Symbol{X}
\begin{document}
\section{Quotation Marks}
%\enquote{test}
\glqq test 2\grqq

\section{TikZ}
% needed:  ======
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolwidth{0.5*width(\string"\Symbol\string")}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\symbolheight{0.5*height(\string"\Symbol\string")}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\symbolwidth, y=\symbolheight]
\node[draw] at (0,0) {\Symbol};
\node[draw] at (4,0) {\Symbol};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the babel library changes " inside tikzpicture (and there the pgf command would work).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's the reason, but apparently the OP wants to use it *before* the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: yes, but in this case you have to do what you always have to do if the active chars interferes: Use \shorthandoff (or string as you suggested)