# istgame package: Problem with display

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, game-tree, istgame

It's my first time using LaTeX and I'm kind of having some problems displaying game trees. I'm using TeXnic Center and MiKTeX and the thing is, I didn't create the following code, i found it in the `istgame` documentation so it is correct. It even works when I paste it on Overleaf but yet when I use it in TeXnic Center this is what it gives me...

I'm pretty sure the problem is quite simple but I sure cannot figure it out by myself so I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hand with that.

[image: So as you can see I obtain a rather annoying graph and I don't understand why.]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[scale=1.5] 
\setistmathTF*001 
\setistgrowdirection{south east} 
\xtdistance{10mm}{20mm} 
\istroot(0)[initial node]{1} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(2,0)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a] \endist 
\istroot(1)(0-2){2} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(1,3)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a] \endist 
\istroot(2)(1-2){1}
    \istb{Take}[r]{(4,2)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a] \endist
\xtInfoset(2-2)([xshift=5mm]2-2)
\istroot(3)([xshift=5mm]2-2){2}
    \istb{Take}[r]{(97,99)}[b] \istb{Pass}[above] \endist 
\istroot(4)(3-2){1} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(100,98)}[b] \istb{Pass}[above] \endist 
\istroot(5)(4-2){2} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(99,101)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a]{(100,100)}[r] \endist 
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Newbie add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}`

Comment: @AndréC THANK YOU! You're my hero

Comment: For archiving, this conversation except the solution has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111512/discussion-on-question-by-newbie-istgame-package-problem-with-display).

Answer (score 2):

## A related post: [Problem with babel and tikz using `\draw`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw)

#### Error producing code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Solution: \usetikzlibrary{babel}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} %% ADDED

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Answer to the question:

- The following code produces an error when compiled through `latex` and `pdflatex`.

  - No problem with `xelatex` and `lualatex` (in my case).
  - No problem in `istgame` code itself.
- Once you got an error, remove auxiliary files before compiling again.
- It is highly recommended to use `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` when `babel` package is uploaded.

  - See TikZ manual on p.130 and Section 44.

output:

[image]

code:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[scale=1.5] 
\setistmathTF*001 
\setistgrowdirection{south east} 
\xtdistance{10mm}{20mm} 
\istroot(0)[initial node]{1} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(2,0)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a] \endist 
\istroot(1)(0-2){2} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(1,3)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a] \endist 
\istroot(2)(1-2){1}
    \istb{Take}[r]{(4,2)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a] \endist
\xtInfoset(2-2)([xshift=5mm]2-2)
\istroot(3)([xshift=5mm]2-2){2}
    \istb{Take}[r]{(97,99)}[b] \istb{Pass}[above] \endist 
\istroot(4)(3-2){1} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(100,98)}[b] \istb{Pass}[above] \endist 
\istroot(5)(4-2){2} 
    \istb{Take}[r]{(99,101)}[b] \istb{Pass}[a]{(100,100)}[r] \endist 
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```