# Problem with subfigure and circuitikz

Tags: subfloats, circuitikz

I have a problema when i want to put a circuit inside a **subfigure**. The problem is on ">" and "<", because if i take off these, the code works!

I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfigure[circuit]{
    \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75,transform shape]
        \draw   (0,0) coordinate (base)
                (base)  to [R,l=$R_2$]  ++ (0,-3) node[ground]{}
                (base)  to [R,l_=$R_1$] ++ (0,3)
                        to [short,-*]           ++ (2.5,0) coordinate (cole);
        \draw   (base)  to [open]   ++ (2.5,0) node[npn](Q){}
                (base)  to [short,*-, f < = $I_B$]     (Q.B)
                %HERE THE PROBLEM! ("f < =")
                (Q.E)   to [R,l=$R_E$]      ++ (0,-2.25) node [ground]{}
                (Q.C)   to [R,l_=$R_C$] (cole);
        \draw   (cole)  to [short]  ++ (3,0) 
                        to [battery,l=$V_{CC}$]     ++ (0,-6) node[ground]{};
    \end{circuitikz}
    }

\end{figure}
```

The error is:

```
Argument of \language@active@arg< has an extra }. }
```

if i put the package: "subcaption" the error is:

```
Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfigure package. \subcaption@CheckCompatibility
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to small but complete document, which reproduce your  problem. It seems that you use obsolete `subfigure` package. Try to replace it by `subfig` or even better `subcaption` package and accordingly replace `subfigure` with code defined in the mentioned packages.

Comment: It's `f<=`, no spaces between `f` and `<`

Comment: I just added more information about the problem!

Comment: Also notice that the error you cite now, `Argument of \language@active@arg< has an extra }.`, is *very* typically related to `babel`. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw --- even if it's a different char, the problem (could) be similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different issues, one is use of obsolete package, the other is typing/syntax error writing (which is solved by @rmano answer). Let me note, that in your particular case, so far it seems that you not have a problems with use obsolete package.

Regarding first, you have two options:

- use of the `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx, nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{subfig} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\subfloat[ subfloat caprion, if needed] 
{
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw   (0,0)   coordinate (aux1)
                to [R=$R_1$]    ++  (0,-3)  coordinate (base)
                to [short,*-,f< = $I_B$]    ++  (2,0)   node[right,npn](Q){}
        (base)  to [R=$R_2$]    ++  (0,-3)  coordinate (aux2)   node [ground]{}
        (aux1)  to [short,*-]   (aux1 -| Q.C)
                to [R=$R_C$]    (Q.C)
        (Q.E)   to [R=$R_E$]    (Q.E |- aux2)  node [ground]{}
(aux1 -| Q.C)   to [short,*-]   ++ (2,0)    coordinate (aux3)
                to [battery,l=$V_{CC}$] (aux3 |- aux2)  node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
}
\caption{Main caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- use of the `subcaption`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[siunitx, nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{subcaption} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\draw   (0,0)   coordinate (aux1)
                to [R=$R_1$]    ++  (0,-3)  coordinate (base)
                to [short,*-,f< = $I_B$]    ++  (2,0)   node[right,npn](Q){}
        (base)  to [R=$R_2$]    ++  (0,-3)  coordinate (aux2)   node [ground]{}
        (aux1)  to [short,*-]   (aux1 -| Q.C)
                to [R=$R_C$]    (Q.C)
        (Q.E)   to [R=$R_E$]    (Q.E |- aux2)  node [ground]{}
(aux1 -| Q.C)   to [short,*-]   ++ (2,0)    coordinate (aux3)
                to [battery,l=$V_{CC}$] (aux3 |- aux2)  node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
    \caption{sub figure caption, if needed}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where is this particular case the same as before. For image code is used code from @rmano answer (+1).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatiasTevez, you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The error is:

```bash
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/f <', to which you passed '$I_B$', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Notice that the Ti*k*Z parser thinks that you used the key `f <`, and it does not recognize it.

If you change it to the real key, which is `f<` (no space), it'll work.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, nooldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.75,transform shape]
    \draw   (0,0) coordinate (base)
    (base)  to [R,l=$R_2$]  ++ (0,-3) node[ground]{}
    (base)  to [R,l_=$R_1$] ++ (0,3)
    to [short,-*]           ++ (2.5,0) coordinate (cole);
    \draw   (base)  to [open]   ++ (2.5,0) node[npn](Q){}
    (base)  to [short,*-, f< = $I_B$]     (Q.B)
    %HERE THE PROBLEM! ("f < =") is a different key than "f<="
    (Q.E)   to [R,l=$R_E$]      ++ (0,-2.25) node [ground]{}
    (Q.C)   to [R,l_=$R_C$] (cole);
    \draw   (cole)  to [short]  ++ (3,0) 
    to [battery,l=$V_{CC}$]     ++ (0,-6) node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the apport, but is not the error. The error is:
"Argument of \language@active@arg< has an extra }. }".
It's only when use "subfigure".

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!!