# Combination of babel - czech and tikzpicture

Tags: babel

Why does \usepackage[czech]{babel} make problem in this code, please?

I obtain an error:  Missing number, treated as zero.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz,fouriernc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\definecolor{lime}{RGB}{0,0,128}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
\shorthandoff{-} %edit
\lhead{ }

        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]     

            \node[yshift=-10cm,lime] at (7.5,10) {\scalebox{3}{Text}};

        \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\shorthandoff{-}` after `\begin{document}`. Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw.

Comment: Do you mean that what I edit in my question? I obtained an error: Undefined control sequence. \shorthandoff{-}

Comment: `\shorthandoff{-}` works fine on my machine. Without your `log` file, any further suggestion would be rather trial/error. On ther other hand, TikZ v3.0.0 has a `babel`-library. Including it in your preamble as `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` could help.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped.