The part "<->" in \draw[<->] doesn’t work
Here is my code:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0.8) {$a$};
    \node (B) at (0.5,0.8) {$b$};
    \node (C) at (1,0.8) {$c$};
    \node (D) at (1.5,0.8) {$d$};
    \node (node1) at (0,0) {$\triangle$};
    \node (node2) at (.5,0) {$\square$};
    \node (node3) at (1,0) {$\bigcirc$};
    \node (node4) at (1.5,0) {$+$};
    % Dibujar las flechas
    \draw[-] (A) -- (node1);
    \draw[-] (B) -- (node2);
    \draw[-] (C) -- (node3);
    \draw[-] (D) -- (node4);
\end{tikzpicture}

at this point, it works, but I want the [<->] inside the brackets.
I’ve tried \usepackage{tikz}, \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}, but it doesn´t work, I’m using MacTex

Can you post a complete MWE with a \documentclass{} and everything? Also, could you provide a commented out code line where it isn't working? Thanks

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166772/problem-with-babel-and-tikz-using-draw

Diego. Based on the fact that there is a comment in Spanish in your code, I dare to assume that you might be using \usepackage[spanish]{babel}. Babel makes < and > active characters to use them for spanish quotation marks (<<texto entre comillas>>).
Add this in the preamble:
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
Saludos!

Can you please translate your answer into English? Thank you

The only language allowed here is English. It does not need to be perfect - use e.g. google translate.

Muchas gracias, eso solucionó mi problema!

@DiegoAntonio De nada! Y bienvenido!
