# Blend/transparency styles in pstricks and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, transparency

As depicted below, Illustrator offers various transparency styles:

[image]

It is my understanding that, at this point, pstricks and TikZ are both limited to the `normal` style listed above. Could the other styles be implemented as well or is there any unexpected limitation somewhere?

Comment: Look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162018/14500 .

Comment: @PaulGaborit That's fairly sad: I up-voted your post some time ago, but completely overlooked it when I posed my question. In a way, I was looking for examples with a picture in the background.

Comment: A specific question about blend modes is better than a vague question about new features. ;-)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Both `pstricks` and `PGF`/`TikZ` can produce all the required blend modes. However it seems that `pstricks.tex` in TeXLive 2013 (a) only defines some of the blend modes supported by ghostscript (at least from version 9.14), and (b) has a bug where `Ligten` should read `Lighten`.

It is (as far as I can tell) quite simple to amend this, although I should caution I am no `pstricks` expert. The following shows all the blend modes for both packages and should be compiled with `xelatex`. It may not work with earlier versions of ghostscript.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter

\pst@def{setBlendmode}<
    \ifcase\psk@blendmode
      /Normal \or 
      /Compatible \or
      /Screen \or
      /Multiply \or
      /HardLight \or
      /Darken \or
      /Lighten \or
      /Difference \or
      /ColorDodge \or
      /ColorBurn \or
      /SoftLight \or
      /Hue \or
      /Saturation \or
      /Luminosity \or
      /Overlay \or
      /Exclusion \or
      /Color
    \else
      /Normal 
    \fi
    .setblendmode \psk@shapealpha .setshapealpha >
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{%
  ps blend mode/.style={/ps blend mode/.cd, #1/.try},
  ps blend mode/.cd,
  normal/.code=\psset{blendmode=0},
  compatible/.code=\psset{blendmode=1},
  screen/.code=\psset{blendmode=2},
  multiply/.code=\psset{blendmode=3},
  hard light/.code=\psset{blendmode=4},
  darken/.code=\psset{blendmode=5},
  lighten/.code=\psset{blendmode=6},
  difference/.code=\psset{blendmode=7},
  color dodge/.code=\psset{blendmode=8},
  color burn/.code=\psset{blendmode=9},
  soft light/.code=\psset{blendmode=10},
  hue/.code=\psset{blendmode=11},
  saturation/.code=\psset{blendmode=12},
  luminosity/.code=\psset{blendmode=13},
  overlay/.code=\psset{blendmode=14},
  exclusion/.code=\psset{blendmode=15},
  color/.code=\psset{blendmode=16}
}

\def\psshowblend#1{%
\psset{unit=0.5cm,fillstyle=shape,linestyle=none,shapealpha=0.75}%
\pgfkeys{ps blend mode=#1}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{pspicture}[shift=-1.5](-1.5,-1.5)(4.5,1.5)
\pscircle[fillcolor=red](.5;90){1}
\pscircle[fillcolor=green](.5;210){1}
\pscircle[fillcolor=blue](.5;330){1}
\rput(3,0){
\pscircle[fillcolor=yellow](.5;90){1}
\pscircle[fillcolor=cyan](.5;210){1}
\pscircle[fillcolor=magenta](.5;330){1}
}
\end{pspicture}
}

\def\tikzshowblend#1{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm, blend mode=#1, opacity=0.75, baseline={(0,0)}]
\useasboundingbox (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (4.5,1.5);
\fill [red]  ( 90:.5) circle [radius=1];
\fill [green]    (210:.5) circle [radius=1];
\fill [blue] (330:.5) circle [radius=1];
\tikzset{shift=(0:3)}
\fill [yellow]  ( 90:.5) circle [radius=1];
\fill [cyan]    (210:.5) circle [radius=1];
\fill [magenta] (330:.5) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\catcode`\|=13
\def|{\verb|}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{5in}
\hskip1in\hbox to 2in{\hfil|pstricks|\hfil}\hbox to 2in{\hfil|tikz|\hfil}\par
\vskip0.5cm%
\foreach \mode in {normal, multiply, screen, overlay, darken, lighten, color dodge, color burn, hard light, soft light, difference, exclusion, hue, saturation, color, luminosity}{%
\leavevmode\hbox to 1in{\tt\mode\hfil}%
\hbox to 2in{\hfil\psshowblend{\mode}\hfil}%
\hbox to 2in{\hfil\tikzshowblend{\mode}\hfil}\hfil\par%
}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Following the OP's comment above, here is some examples with a picture in the background using only `TikZ` this time (`pstricks` can do it as well, I am just more familiar with `TikZ`).

The picture is not very exciting but the code overlays red, green and blue circles at varying levels of transparency to illustrate the different blend modes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \mode [count=\n from 0, evaluate={\x=mod(\n,2)*5; \y=-floor(\n/2)*4;}] in {normal, multiply, screen, overlay, darken, lighten, color dodge, color burn, hard light, soft light, difference, exclusion, hue, saturation, color, luminosity}{%
  \begin{scope}[shift={(\x,\y)},local bounding box=mode]
  \foreach \c [count=\i] in {red, green, blue}{
    \foreach \j [evaluate={\o=(\j+1)/4;}] in {0,...,3}{
      \begin{scope}[shift=(90:2-\i), shift=(0:\j), scale=0.25]
        \begin{scope}[opacity=0.75]
          \fill [red]   ( 90:.5) circle [radius=1];
          \fill [green] (210:.5) circle [radius=1];
          \fill [blue]  (330:.5) circle [radius=1];
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[blend mode=\mode, opacity=\o]
          \fill [fill=\c] circle [radius=1.875];
        \end{scope}  
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
  \end{scope}
  \node [above] at (mode.north) {\tt\mode};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

PSTricks knows one more fill style for transparent colors: shape with
using the shapealpha value and one of the possible blendmodes. More can easily be realized if they are supported by Ghostscript:

> - /Normal      ->0
> - /Compatible  ->1
> - /Screen      ->2
> - /Multiply    ->3
> - /HardLight   ->4
> - /Darken      ->5
> - /Lighten     ->6
> - /Difference  ->7

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\Frames{%
\psframe*[linecolor=red](0,1)(3,4)
\psframe[fillcolor=blue,fillstyle=shape](2,2)(5,5)
\psframe[fillcolor=green,fillstyle=shape](1,0)(4,3)
\pscircle[fillcolor=cyan,fillstyle=shape,shapealpha=0.3](1.5,3.5){1.25}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)% default blendmode
\Frames\rput(1.5,3.5){\huge\textbf{0}}
\end{pspicture}
\hfill
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psset{blendmode=1}% type /Compatible
\Frames\rput(1.5,3.5){\huge\textbf{1}}
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psset{blendmode=2}% type /Screen
\Frames\rput(1.5,3.5){\huge\textbf{2}}
\end{pspicture}
\hfill
\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psset{blendmode=3}% type /Multiply
\Frames\rput(1.5,3.5){\huge\textbf{3}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have several questions about this: 1)Is this documented? (I couldn't find supported blend modes explained in the PSTricks PDF manual); 2)Can blend modes be used with lines too, or only with filled areas? ...and 3) Is there any way of getting additive transparency? (so that R+G+B=White)

Comment: run `texdoc pst-news08` or see https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/base/doc