# XeLaTeX can't use TikZ 3 features?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, luatex

I copied this code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162018/48097) answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz [blend group=screen] {
  \fill[red!90!black]   ( 90:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[green!80!black] (210:.6) circle (1);
  \fill[blue!90!black] (330:.6) circle (1);
}
\end{document}
```

I compiled it with XeLaTeX, the result is the following:

[image: XeLaTeX output]

(FYI it's just a white square)

And this is the output from pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX:

[image: pdfLaTeX output]

Which is what I was hoping for.

Is this some kind of bug in XeLaTeX? Did I miss something?

**Edit**: Mark Wibrow in the comments linked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183044/blend-transparency-styles-in-pstricks-and-tikz/183050#183050) answer, that was compiled with xelatex. Now, my experience with tikz and related graphic packages is very limited: I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong here, but even if it's somehow fixable I'm pretty sure that xelatex and lualatex shouldn't produce such different outcomes.

Comment: It's not a bug but a known shortcoming. These features are even new for many PDF viewers let alone TeX engines. And XeLaTeX uses a fundamentally different way of creating PDF.

Comment: Oh, ok... I guess this means that there's no way to do it with xelatex ):

Comment: @izabera  [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183050) answer using blend modes in both `PGF` and `PSTricks` was compiled with xelatex from TeX-live 2013.

Comment: @MarkWibrow Thank you. Now I'm a bit puzzled, what's going wrong with my example?

Comment: @izabera I don't know. Your MWE compiles fine for me with `xelatex` and produces the intended result. Possibly a version problem. The command `xelatex --version` gives me `XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2013060708 (TeX Live 2013)`.

Comment: @MarkWibrow How weird, mine is newer! `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014/W32TeX)`, last version of TeXLive on Windows 8

Comment: @MarkWibrow I can reproduce the error with `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014)`. I can also reproduce with `XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2013060708 (TeX Live 2013)`. With `XeTeX 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012)`, I get a complaint about `blend mode` but I do get the circles in the PDF - just not blended as expected with an older version of `tikz`. This is GNU/Linux x86_64. Not sure why you don't see the problem with the same version of XeTeX as my 2013 one.

Comment: @cfr Hmm, I'm on GNU/Linux x86_64 as well. What is your `ghostscript` version? Mine is `9.14`.

Comment: @cfr actually it's nothing to to do with `ghostscript` or `xelatex`, it is beacuase I am using the latest CVS version of `PGF`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `PGF` releases on CTAN and sourceforge contain a bug where the interaction of shadings/transparency and the `standalone` package and `xelatex` (and `xdvipdfmx`) causes problems.

The code will work if, for example, the document class is set to `article` (and, obviously `\usepackage{tikz}` is added to the preamble).

This was fixed in the CVS version back in January.