# Is there any recolor feature for imported images in LaTeX?

Tags: color

Is there any feature in LaTeX to recolor a figure which is included in a LaTeX .tex file automatically like the feature which exists in programs like Word? It is a good feature, for instance the person has to bring different logos in his presentation slides and each are in different colors, by this feature he will be able to automatically recolor the logos to suite his presentation theme.

**Before Recolor**
[image]

**After Recolor**
[image]

Comment: You mean change the color of an external image? Or the color of some words *written in LaTeX*?

Comment: Recolor of an external image.

Comment: Then no, not in general for external images. (La)TeX cannot manipulate the pixel data; it only includes that data with appropriate scale/rotate operations applied.

Comment: Related: [Can \includegraphics be used to change an image color?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29227/can-includegraphics-be-used-to-change-an-image-color)

Comment: Well LaTeX "could" do this in the sense that if its run with `--shell-escape` enabled then you could farm the job out to an external program and then pull the recoloured image back. But *should* LateX do this? I don't think that doctoring external images is part of LaTeX's remit.

Comment: Look at my [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74107/14500) to [Coloring a black and white PDF graphic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74087/14500).

Comment: Since TikZ/pgf 3.0, there is also a solution via [`blend mode`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162018/14500)...

Answer (score 19):

Here is a possible solution for simple cases using `blend mode` (`logo.png` is your first B&W logo):

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node{\includegraphics{logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group=lighten];
    \begin{scope}[blend group=difference]
      \node[inner sep=0,line width=0] (logo) {\includegraphics{logo}};
      \fill[black] (logo.south west) rectangle (logo.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \fill[orange] (logo.south west) rectangle (logo.north east);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group=lighten];
    \begin{scope}[blend group=difference]
      \node[inner sep=0,line width=0] (logo) {\includegraphics{logo}};
      \fill[black] (logo.south west) rectangle (logo.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \fill[blue!70] (logo.south west) rectangle (logo.north east);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was completely mind blown by this answer. After finding [this question on the available blend groups](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183044/blend-transparency-styles-in-pstricks-and-tikz), I started experimenting a bit. The `multiply` option was especially useful for me in combination with some color to tint a picture (with white bg) to my non-white background. Am I right, that everything inside a scope will be treated as defined by the blend group so if there is just one thing inside nothing would happen?

Comment: @gr4nt3d Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: This answer should triple count the votes

Answer (score -3):

No, it's not possible.

If you want to create a nice logo.
You can use PowerPoint and have all its great capabilities.
Save single slide as PDF and include the graphic with:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, trim=0cm 4cm 0cm 4cm,clip=true]{images/mylogo.pdf}
        \label{fig:mylogo}
\end{figure}
```

With the option `trim` you can easily crop the logo and delete white spaces.
PDF is a great format, because you keep the lossless resize feature of PowerPoint.

PS: I am using MS Office, but LibreOffice should be just as well.