# Is there a way to "colorize" a line drawing?

Tags: graphics

I have a few line drawings (see the attached example; pardon the hideous green), basically black & white with occasional shades of gray and a transparent background (in .png format). I know how to include these pictures in my documents.

Is there a way to “colorize” them, [image]for want of a better word, so that the black lines will appear in a different color? I can, of course, do this in image editing software, but would like to be able to do this on the fly in `LaTeX`(any flavor).

Any pointers?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196364/is-there-any-recolor-feature-for-imported-images-in-latex

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I _did_ search before asking, using, alas, the wrong terms. I'll go check it out.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `decodearray={rmin rmax gmin gmax bmin bmax}` option to `\includegraphics` (the default colour coding is `decodearray={0 1 0 1 0 1}`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 1 0 1 0 1},width=\textwidth]{ingmar.png}\\
\includegraphics[decodearray={1 1 0 1 0 1},width=\textwidth]{ingmar.png}\\
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 1 1 1 0 1},width=\textwidth]{ingmar.png}\\
\includegraphics[decodearray={0 1 0 1 1 1},width=\textwidth]{ingmar.png}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, any idea why this doesn't work with `example-image`?

Comment: @campa Try `example-image.png` instead of `.pdf`. The Decode array will be applied to a single object in the pdf, but an image from a pdf file contains more than a single object, so `decodearray` isn't used

Comment: @campa Also `example-image.png` seems to be monochrome (not only visually, but some property of the image) because only the first two channels of `decodearray` have any effect on it.  The other ones are just ignored.  For example, `\includegraphics[decodearray={1 0}]{example-image.png}` inverts the colour

Comment: That's what got me also: make sure the images you work with are actually in RGB (not Grayscale) mode.

Comment: @Ingmar Yes, `decodearray` will just act on each channel of the image, so if it has only one channel it won't "add" colour.  It sort of "tunes" the existing channels.  I'm was looking for an official reference on this, but couldn't find one that explains _exactly_ how it works...

Comment: `decodearray` corresponds to the optional `/Decode` key of an image dictionary in PDF. From the PDF reference, I understand `/Decode` cannot change color space. If an image uses `DeviceGray` color space, then `/Decode` won't make it more "colorful".

Answer (score 22):

TikZ offers lots of possibilities of "filters" (not what kids these days know as filters, please) to apply over an image by using PDF transparency layers. Section 23.3
(Blend Modes) of the [TikZ manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) explains this feature with the possible "blend modes": `normal`, `multiply`, `screen`, `overlay`, `darken`, `lighten`, `color dodge`, `color burn`, `hard light`, `soft light`, `difference`, `exclusion`, `hue`, `saturation`, `color` and `luminosity`.  Taking the example from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196384/171234), you can mix different blend modes to get interesting effects:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=10cm]{hBg1w.png}

\newcommand\colorize[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group=#1]
    \begin{scope}[blend group=#2]
      \node[inner sep=0pt] (logo) {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{hBg1w}};
      \fill[white] (logo.south west) rectangle (logo.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \fill[red] (logo.south west) rectangle (logo.north east);
  \end{scope}
  \node (logo.south) [below=.5cm,font=\Large] {#1/#2};
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\colorize{screen}{overlay}
\colorize{overlay}{saturation}

%\colorize{screen}{normal}
%\colorize{screen}{multiply}
%\colorize{screen}{screen}
%\colorize{screen}{overlay}
%\colorize{screen}{darken}
%\colorize{screen}{lighten}
%\colorize{screen}{color dodge}
%\colorize{screen}{color burn}
%\colorize{screen}{hard light}
%\colorize{screen}{soft light}
%\colorize{screen}{difference}
%\colorize{screen}{exclusion}
%\colorize{screen}{hue}
%\colorize{screen}{saturation}
%\colorize{screen}{color}
%\colorize{screen}{luminosity}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's beautiful about this approach is that you can, more or less, map different grays to colors with difference hue.  For instance, with some clever combinations you can probably make darker area reddish while making lighter area yellowish.