# How to colorize a grayscale icon on a non-white background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, color, transparency

I have a black on transparent icon in a png file. I want to use this icon at different locations in a LaTeX document in different colors.
As a bonus it would be good if I can give the upper half of the icon a different color than the lower half because it sometimes appears on the border of different backgrounds.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196364/is-there-any-recolor-feature-for-imported-images-in-latex/196384#196384) shows how to colorize a grayscale png file and it's easy to give the upper half a different color than the lower half. Unfortunately, it requires the logo to be on a white background:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[yellow!50!white] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[gray!50!black]   (0,0) rectangle (2,1);

    \begin{scope}[blend group=screen]
        \node[inner sep=0,line width=0] (logo) at (1,1) [anchor=center] {\includegraphics{icon-bw}};
        \fill[blue] (logo.west) rectangle (logo.north east);
        \fill[green] (logo.south west) rectangle (logo.east);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

An example icon with white background added:
[image: icon-bw.png]

If I use a black to transparent png instead the entire node is painted blue and green.

An example icon with transparent background:
[image: icon.png]

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74087/coloring-a-black-and-white-pdf-graphic/74107#74107) shows how to use a png file as transparency mask.
But how do I move the icon so that it's centered at (1,1)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=icon]
    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
    \node (icon) [fill, draw, white] {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{icon}};
    \begin{scope}[blend mode=difference]
    \fill[white] (icon.south west) rectangle (icon.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[yellow!50!white] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[gray!50!black]   (0,0) rectangle (2,1);

    % How I intend to use it
    \begin{scope}[scope fading=icon, fit fading=false]
        \fill[blue] (0.5,1) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
        \fill[green] (0.5,0.5) rectangle (1.5,1);
    \end{scope}

    % Approach of the original answer. The icon is not positioned correctly.
    % The specified coordinate does not seem to make any difference.
    \path[scope fading=icon,fit fading=false] (1,1);
    \node[fill=yellow,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=1cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In my real use case the icon consists of black and transparency, only. So it would be acceptable if an answer does not work with intermediate gray tones.

Comment: Without icon.png your code cannot be executed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo icon.png is the second image in the question. The first image is icon-bw.png. They are rendered very similar here on the webpage but the first has a white background, the second has a transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer differs from John Kormylo's mainly in two points:

- I am using `fading transform` where I am applying the fading instead of `\hspace` and `\raisebox` in the fading definition. Also note that I am using `path fading` instead of `scope fading`. I am not sure how big of a difference that is but I did not get it working with passing `scope fading` and `fading transform` to a `scope` environment.
- I am inverting the colors of the png file so that the black parts are filled instead of the transparent parts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand\IconNodeContent{%
    \includegraphics[height=1cm]{icon}%
}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=icon]
    % I am using \fill[white] with blend mode=difference to invert the colors
    % so that I can use my black on transparent icon without needing to convert it to white on transparent/black.
    % This has the down side that the area around the icon node is not transparent but opaque.
    % I am increasing the transparent area a little with draw thick to avoid a visible rectangle around the icon when filling it later.
    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
    \node (icon) [fill, draw, thick, white] {\IconNodeContent};
    \begin{scope}[blend mode=difference]
    \fill[white] (icon.south west) rectangle (icon.north east);
    \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % draw background
    \fill[yellow!50!white] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
    \fill[gray!50!black]   (0,0) rectangle (2,1);

    % create an invisible node to define size and position of icon
    \node (icon) at (1,1) [anchor=center, transparent] {\IconNodeContent};
    % draw the top half of the icon in one color, shifting the coordinates 1pt inwards to make sure no border is visible
    \fill[blue,  path fading=icon, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(icon.center)}] ([shift={(1pt,-1pt)}] icon.north west) rectangle ([shift={(-1pt,+0pt)}] icon.east);
    % draw the bottom half of the icon in another color, shifting the coordinates 1pt inwards to make sure no border is visible
    \fill[green, path fading=icon, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(icon.center)}] ([shift={(1pt,+1pt)}] icon.south west) rectangle ([shift={(-1pt,-0pt)}] icon.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

The fading pattern will be centered about (0,0), and the only way to move it is to move the node contents using things like `\hspace` and `\raisebox`.  Moving the implementation just uses the pattern at that location (off the edge).  Since it is centered, you have to move it twice as far as it actually moves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=icon,inner sep=0]
  \node [fill=transparent!0]
    {\hspace{2cm}\raisebox{2cm}{\includegraphics[height=2cm, width=2cm]{images/icon}}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[yellow!50!white] (0,1) rectangle (2,2);
  \fill[gray!50!black]   (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
  \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
    \path[scope fading=icon, fit fading=false];
    \node[bottom color=blue,top color=green,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was not quite happy with using `\hspace` and `\raisebox` in the fading definition, though. Instead I have found a different way using `fading transform` where I am applying the fading.